# VS 2010 - copy XSDs when building solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I have a website (MVC) and some other projects in the same solution.
In one of those separate projects I have some XSDs that I want copied to the bin folder of the website on build.

I have specified the XSDs as content and copy always but they only get copied to that project's bin/debug folder not the bin of the website.

Is there any way of having them copied to the website's bin?

Is it possible to write a post-build script to deploy these files to the project flagged as StartUp in a solution?

The bigger picture - I just want to validate some generated xmls against these XSDs, but dont want to have these XSDs as content in every solution that uses this project.

Cannot use the XSDs as embedded resources because of import statements in the XSDs referencing each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have flagged these XSDs as content and copy always to output folder.
For some reason this doesn't copy them when building/publish the solution on my local machine through VS, but it works when running a TFS build.
Good enough I guess...